# Using $_GET in a javascript file parsed with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, get, content-type

I have a javascript file I parsed with PHP using

```
(PARENT)
<script src='js/function.php' type='application/javascript'></script>
```

and

```
(FUNCTION.PHP)
header("Content-type: application/javascript");
```

In this file I need to access query values from the parent document. I have noticed that using $_GET is not returning any values and I'm assuming because its only looking at the function.php file and not it's parent file. Is there any way to access the query values from the parent without passing them down to the function.php file through its own query?

I've done a bit of looking around but can't seem to find an answer.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What if `<script src='js/function.php?v=1&p=3'`?

Comment: I was hoping not to have to pass down the query to funciton.php but it's looking like that is my only option huh? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I guess passing the query isn't THAT big of a deal. Just curious if there were any other options mainly

Comment: `PARENT` and `FUNCTION.PHP` are two different HTTP requests. So they have two different `$_GET` variables. You could use the `$_SESSION` to store values of the first request useful to the second request. That's the best method to share context between both requests

Comment: Thank you guys for your input, I used $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] to just pass the query to function.php